# Javascript Problem! Not changing the css style

Tags: javascript

I have this code in JavaScript:

```
function change() {

        document.getElementById("mem").className = 'gif';

}
```

The fig and gif are like this:

```
a.fig {

background: #FFFFFF;

}

a.gif {

background: #000099  ;
}
```

and the function is used like this

```
<a class ="fig" id ="mem" onClick="javascript:change()" href="users" >
```

Where the only difference between *gif* and *fig* in CSS is that they have different background colors.  The problem is that the change is only noticeable in just a second and it is not permanent!

Any ideas?

Comment: How `change()` is called? Are you aware the `if` statement is meaningless?

Comment: You're setting the same class ('gif') for both if statement possibilities.

Comment: I'm confused... both `if` and `else` set the `className` to `gif`? Why have `if-else` then?

Comment: yes I know if statement is useless . Just tried something..

Comment: i use it like this 
<a class ="fig" id ="mem" onClick="javascript:change()" href="users"> MEMBERS </a>

Comment: just nevermind the if-else statement. Just dont know why it changes just for a second and why the change is not permanent

Comment: @mathew you'll have to show more code - the key here is very much the changing back which suggests multiple events.

Comment: @mathew Try `onclick="change()"`. I don't think the `javascript:` protocol is welcome inside onevent attributes...

Comment: Just add return false: `onClick="change(); return false;"` the thing is that without it, the class is changed then the page is redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function change() {
var mem = document.getElementById("mem");
    if (mem.className == 'fig') {
        mem.className = 'gif';
    }
    else {
        mem.className = 'fig';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<a id="mem" class="fig" href="users"> MEMBERS </a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var a = document.getElementById('mem');

a.onclick = function() {
    this.className = this.className == 'fig' ? 'gif' : 'fig';
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/eVQjB/

Note: in the demo, I `return false;` from the click handler to prevent the anchor from being activated.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a different problem with JavaScript and styles, but if I understand your problem, you'll still need a different color for the anchor if it has been visited. You can let CSS do that for you:

```
#mem {
  background: #FFF;
}

#mem:visited {
  background: #009;
}

<a id="mem" href="users">Lead me to the promised land!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try by following way

```
document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("class", "className");
```

IF still not working you r class is not chaning the style of your html element

Answer (score 0):

Just add return false:

```
onClick="change(); return false;"
```

The thing is that without it, the class is changed then the page is redirected as this is the default behavior of anchor tag.

If you want to reload the page and change the class in the reloaded page, have such link:

```
href="?change=true"
```

Then in the server side code check for this flag and if true put different class. I'm not familiar with PHP but here is classic ASP version, hopefully similar enough to PHP:

```
<%
Dim sClassName
If Request("change")="true" Then
   sClassName = "gif"
Else  
   sClassName = "fig"
End If
%>
<a class ="<%=sClassName%>" id ="mem" href="?change=true">
```

Comment: Well it does work just fine.. But it apparently does not follow the link because of the return false statement.. But i need both the color to be changed and the link to be folowed.. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @mat so what you really need is different approach: have the link send flag over the URL then if the flag exists, put different class. Do you have server side language at your disposal? Another way is using AJAX.

Comment: Yes i work mainly in PHP.. But i dont really understand what you mean. Can you explain me a little more please? Sorry for being a pain in the ass...